# MVC API controller error with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

i have a simple controller where i am using the interfaec like this ,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    private IHotelService hotelService;
    public HomeController(IHotelService _hotelService)
    {
        hotelService = _hotelService;
    }
}
```

its working fine, but when i use same thing with API controller like

```
public class RoomController : BaseApiController
{
    private IHotelService hotelService;
    public RoomController(IHotelService _hotelService)
    {
        hotelService = _hotelService;
    }
```

it gives me error

Comment: Please post the error message or log here

Comment: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'RoomController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: If you read here then you can understand that why that error message is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx
Create a constructor without any parameter.

Comment: How are your injecting the service? What DI framework are you using?

Comment: i am using ninject web common for DI , and its working fine with normal web controller but not with api controller that is the actual problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5, Web API 2 and Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595472/mvc5-web-api-2-and-ninject)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41694725/181087) (and in several other answers on SO), you have most likely not registered your DI container with Web API. Web API is a *separate framework* than MVC and therefore it has a separate configuration, including dependency injection.

So, you need to set

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = MyDependencyResovler(container);
```

at application startup. The details of how to do this depend on what container you are actually using and whether you use a stock dependency resolver or roll your own as shown in [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).